# Getting slope from DEM.tif using Spatial Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, spatial-analyst, slope

I have a DEM.tif file and I want to get the slope. I know I use the Slope tool from Spatial Analyst. But, I'm confused which output_measurement to choose from (i.e degrees or percent rise). Basically, I am trying to find areas where the slope < 5%.

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/how-slope-works.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <5% that you want could also be written as "less than five percent rise", so you want to output "percent rise". In general degrees or percent rise are just two different ways to measure the same slope. The ArcGIS ["How Slope Works"](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-slope-works.htm) page explains the math of how you convert from one to the other with some basic trigonometry, as shown in this diagram from that page:

[image: Diagram showing the geometry to convert between slope in percent rise versus degrees.]

Comment: im just confused because it talks about how 45 degrees = 100%. So, does that mean when u select degrees it shows values as %'s?

Comment: No, it just means that those are equivalent slopes. I.e. two different ways to describe the same steep chunk of ground. If you are working with your slope in terms of percent then just set the output_measurement to be PERCENT_RISE and don't worry about degrees. In the output raster places with less than 5% slope will be the raster cells with values under 5. It's just like if you were working with a tool that output values in either meters or feet. If all your data is in feet, then just set the output to feet and completely ignore the meters option.